# Wrapper background image gets cut off at the top

Tags: css, image, background, position

My site has a wrapper with three background images. A static top and bottom image and a third image that repeats along the y axis. For some reason the top background image is getting cut off and I can't figure out way.

Here is a link to the live site: http://storrepictures.weebly.com/projects.html

I have offset the top and bottom images so you can see what they look like. You can see that the top one is cut off. I've tried messing around with some of the div padding settings but can't seem to get it to work.

One interesting note: The background images used to be JPEGs (I switched to PNG files because I needed transparency). When I was using JPEGs this was not a problem - the three images lined up perfectly.

Let me know if it would help to have the actual code posted. From what I've been reading on this forum, people seem to like looking at the live site and I didn't want to make the post too long.

Thanks a lot for all your help.

*Here's the CSS:

```
body {

background: #ffffff;
font-family: Tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#666666;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


#wrapper {
    background: url(containerbg.png) center repeat-y;

}

#wrappertop{
background: url(containertop.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 0px -40px; 
}

#wrappertbtm{
background: url(containerbtm.png)   no-repeat;
background-position: 34px 480px;
padding-bottom: 65px;
}
.title{
width: 1022px;
min-height: 30px;
_height: 30px;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
font-size: 30px;
}

.title, .title a {
color: #fff;
}


#container {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 125px;
bottom: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: -300px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#content{
width: 800px;
min-height: 500px;
_height: 500px;
margin: 0pt auto;

}

#content a{
color: #ff6633;
text-decoration: none;
}
.weebly_header{
background: url(%%HEADERIMG%%) no-repeat;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>{title}</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]> 
<style>
    #content
{
    height:400px !important;
} 
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="wsite-theme-light">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="wrappertop">
        <div id="wrappertbtm">
            <div id="container">
                 <div id="header">
                   <div id="headerleft">{logo max-height="60"}</div>
                   <div id="navigation">{menu}</div>        
             </div> 


        <div id="content">{content}
            <div id="footer">{footer}

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: take a closer look at the images content, it seems the bottom image suits for the top part, and vice-versa.

Comment: Are you referring to the body background images? I actually don't think those images are causing the problem. I ended up deleting them and replacing with a plain white background to simplify things for now. I have also cut down the code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your `body` element has `padding` and `margin` values interfering:

```css
body {
    background: url(theme/backgroundtop.jpg?909894) left top repeat-x, 
        url(theme/backgroundbottom.jpg?909894) left bottom repeat-x, 
        url(theme/backgroundmid.jpg?909894) left repeat;
    font-family: Tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666666;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 100px 0 0 0;
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;
}
```

You should get rid of these rules:

```css
body {
    /* ... */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and all should be fine.

***Note:** setting `height: 100%` to the body element is meaningless, you might wanna remove that, too.*

***Note #2:** you have only 3 values for the multiple backgrounds of the body, which will be parsed as T/LR/B, while the order or those values indicates you should change their order, i.e. `backgroundtop / backgroundmid / backgroundbottom` instead of `backgroundtop / backgroundbottom / backgroundmid`*

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I made the changes you suggested but now the entire top of the site is cut off. I have included the CSS and html code in the original post.

Comment: please try and further investigate the area in which the problem occurs, and filter out all unnecessary code. this will help a lot, both for us and for you, to clarify the problem.